# JavaFx On children.clear memory not released

Tags: javafx, memory-leaks, javafx-8

I am loading 1000 list of ImageViews to `TilePane`. And then, after certain period, I am removing all the children of the `TilePane`. But In the Task Manager, I can see the memory not release at all(consumed 6GB RAM).

This is the code

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TilePane tilePane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        File rootPathFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Flower\\3D Objects\\New folder");
        File[] fileList = rootPathFile.listFiles();

        ObservableList<ImageView> btnList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (File file : fileList) {
            Image img = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
            imgView.setFitWidth(200);
            imgView.setFitHeight(300);
            btnList.add(imgView);
        }
        tilePane.getChildren().addAll(btnList);

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("\nAfter adding 1000 images:");
                System.out.println("Free Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                System.out.println("Totel Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());

                Thread.sleep(15000);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    try {
                        tilePane.getChildren().clear();

                        Thread.sleep(5000); // to ensure memory changes
                        System.out.println("\nAfter clearing children:");
                        System.out.println("Free Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                        System.out.println("Totel Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());

                        System.gc();
                        Thread.sleep(10000);

                        System.out.println("\nAfter GC() and 10 seconds sleep");
                        System.out.println("Free Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                        System.out.println("Totel Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
After adding 1000 images:
Free Memory: 1044423528
Totel Memory: 4572839936

After clearing children:
Free Memory: 1035263112
Totel Memory: 4572839936

After GC() and 10 seconds sleep
Free Memory: 1045599688
Totel Memory: 4572839936
```

This is only for demo. In my actual project, I have `ListView` and `TilePane` in the `SplitPane`. Whenever I click item(folder name) in `ListView`, I have to load images(10 to 20 images) to the TilePane by clearing previous children. But its not clearing the memory and keeps increasing.

Comment: hmm .. looks like a bug

Comment: 1. Task Manager is simply going to report the amount of memory allocated to the Java Heap; that doesn't mean that heap space is all being used.  2. The garbage collector won't free space in the heap unless it's actually needed. So, what do `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` report, and what happens if you call `System.gc ()`?

Comment: @James_D I added the outputs in the question

Comment: That test isn't correct (though the issue may still be real): your call to `System.gc()` is likely to happen *before* you call `tilePane.getChildren().clear()`. Move the `System.out.println()` and `System.gc()` calls to the `Platform.runLater()`, after clearing the child list, and see if that changes the output.

Comment: But your call to `System.gc()` will still (probably) happen *before* your call to clear the child list. The `Platform.runLater(...)` schedules code to run on the FX Application thread, so there's likely to be a small pause before it's executed. The code after happens immediately in that thread. So when you call `System.gc()`, the images are still referenced by the UI, and the GC can't do anything. After you clear the images, you just hang around a while, and since there's still plenty of free memory, the GC doesn't get invoked, and so the memory is never cleaned up.

Comment: Move the `gc()` call *inside* the `Platform.runLater()` block (after the call to clear the children), or call it *after* the `sleep()` in the background thread.

Comment: @James_D Updated, but still the same.

Comment: Well, I could still see you getting that output even if there isn't an issue (again, I'm not necessarily saying there isn't an issue). In your real app, do you actually run out of memory (e.g. do you get `OutOfMemoryError`s), or see any performance issues other than the memory increasing in Task Manager (which is expected)? Does the app still work if you limit the memory available to the JVM?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I think your test isn't working as a test of what you want (even in your latest version, calling `clear()` removes the images from the child list of the tile pane, but at that point the images are still physically displayed by the underlying graphics system, and will be until the next "pulse" on the FX application thread. The `sleep()` doesn't help, because it blocks the FX Application Thread.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly convinced there is no issue here.

The Windows Task Manager is not a reliable way to test Java memory consumption. The way the JVM works is that it will set aside some memory for the heap. This memory allocation is reported by `Runtime.getRuntime().getTotalMemory()`. If the heap starts to get full, it will either allocate more memory to the heap (up to `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`), or run the garbage collector to remove unreferenced objects. I believe in current implementations the JVM will not release unused memory assigned to the heap back to the system. You can configure the initial total and max memory using the JVM options `-Xms` and `-Xmx`, respectively.

In your application, as you load images, they will of course consume memory. If needed, the heap size will grow, up to the max memory allocation, and this is the size you see reported by the Windows Task Manager.

When you clear your tile pane, *at some point soon after that* (when the scene is next rendered), the images will be physically removed from the underlying graphics system, and associated resources will be released. At this point, the heap memory is still used by the images, but they are now eligible for garbage collection. The next time the garbage collector runs (which will happen automatically if more memory is needed), that memory will be reclaimed by the heap (but not by the system); so you will see changes in `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`, but not in the Task Manager.

In your test code, you call `System.gc()` after clearing the child list of the tile pane, but before the rendering pulse happens, so the images are not eligible for garbage collection; consequently you see no changes to the `freeMemory()`. (The `sleep()` doesn't help, because it blocks the FX Application thread, preventing it from rendering the scene.) Because there is still plenty of free memory, even with the images loaded, the GC doesn't need to run and isn't invoked automatically.

Here's a more complete test, that allows you to monitor the heap memory usage in real time, and invoke the GC from a button. I tested this on Mac OS X (my host machine) with 4GB of heap space (by default), and also on Windows 10 running on a VM in Oracle VirtualBox, with 1GB heap space and the number of images reduced to 400 (due to memory allocation to the virtual OS). Both exhibited the same results: the memory grows when you load images. If you load fresh images, the GC kicks in automatically and the memory consumption stays more or less constant. If you clear the images, there's no change in the memory, but if you then force the GC, the heap memory is released.

The OS tools (Activity Monitor on Mac and Task Manager on Windows) report a more-or-less constant memory usage, once the heap as hit the max memory allocation.

All this behavior is exactly as expected.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";

    private Image image ;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // download image:
        image = new Image(IMAGE_URL, false);
    };


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
        TilePane imagePane = new TilePane();

        Button load = new Button("Load Images");


        Button clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.setOnAction(e -> imagePane.getChildren().clear());

        Button gc = new Button("GC");
        gc.setOnAction(e -> System.gc());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(load, clear, gc);
        buttons.setSpacing(5);

        load.setOnAction(e -> {
            imagePane.getChildren().clear();
            ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(ProgressIndicator.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
            TilePane.setAlignment(progressIndicator, Pos.CENTER);
            imagePane.getChildren().add(progressIndicator);
            buttons.setDisable(true);

            PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
            int w = (int)image.getWidth();
            int h = (int)image.getHeight();

            Task<List<Image>> createImagesTask = new Task<>() {
                @Override
                public List<Image> call() {

                    // Create 1000 new copies of the image we downloaded
                    // Note: Never do this in real code, you can reuse
                    // the same image for multiple views. This is just
                    // to mimic loading 1000 different images into memory.
                    List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>(1000);
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
                        images.add( new WritableImage(reader, w, h));
                        updateProgress(i, 1000);
                    }
                    return images ;
                }

            };

            progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(createImagesTask.progressProperty());

            createImagesTask.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {

                // Create images views from each of the copies of the image,
                // and add them to the image pane:
                imagePane.getChildren().clear();
                for (Image img : createImagesTask.getValue()) {
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
                    imageView.setFitWidth(200);
                    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                    imagePane.getChildren().add(imageView);
                }
                buttons.setDisable(false);
            });

            Thread t = new Thread(createImagesTask);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        });


        // Labels to display memory usage:            
        Label freeMem = new Label("Free memory:");
        Label usedMem = new Label("Used memory:");
        Label totalMem = new Label("Total memory:");
        Label maxMem = new Label("Max memory:");
        VBox memoryMon = new VBox(freeMem, usedMem, totalMem, maxMem);
        memoryMon.setSpacing(5);


        // use an AnimationTimer to update the memory usage on each
        // rendering pulse:
        AnimationTimer memTimer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                long total = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
                long max = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
                freeMem.setText(String.format("Free memory: %,d", free));
                usedMem.setText(String.format("Used memory: %,d", total-free));
                totalMem.setText(String.format("Total memory: %,d", total));
                maxMem.setText(String.format("Max memory: %,d", max));
            }

        };
        memTimer.start();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(new ScrollPane(imagePane));
        root.setTop(buttons);
        root.setBottom(memoryMon);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure about my sample code, why it consumed 6GB ram and continue showing the same number for while(15 min) after clearing children. But In my actual code I am able to solve the issue by removing `imageView.setCache(true)`. Thanks for the information and code. It helped to understand lot.